# Is Unreal Engine using Monte Carlo path tracing or similar methods?

Tags: rendering, unreal-5

Is Unreal Engine using Monte Carlo path tracing or similar methods in which efficient pseudo random number generators are crucial to make their renders?

I know it is needed for typical renders, but if you create some world in the game, do you also make render of the world?

As someone suggested in comments I'll explain why I'm interested in that topic. I'm interested in PRNG generators and I'm working on my own. I'm wondering if a game developer or Unreal Engine could benefit significantly if, for example, they had a PRNG generator that was 2 times faster than the best generators currently available. The fact that there will be benefits in Monte Carlo path tracing method itself is clear, but I don't know how important this method is in games.

Comment: You would probably receive more useful answers if you explained *why* you need to know that for the game you are developing. The way the question is currently phrased, it's a simple yes/no question, which is not really that insightful or interesting.

Comment: Allow me to add that if you have Unreal engine and are signed up with Epic, Unreal Engine _is_ source-available. You can review it at https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine , after signing up with them and logging in. This may help you in the future with questions like this, even with a simple search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monte Carlo path tracing is more commonly used for offline renders — when you can spend between many seconds to sometimes hours rendering a single frame.

Realtime games have a time budget of milliseconds, so this method is still too slow for drawing frames on demand during gameplay. Instead, games are typically rendered with rasterization, with some special effects filled in with raytracing or raymarching (usually with only single rays per pixel, rather than accumulating hundreds of distinct paths as in MCPT).

It's possible to use slower rendering processes as a pre-processing step at build time, like baking a lightmap that encodes global illumination. Monte Carlo path tracing could potentially be used here, but I'm not familiar enough with Unreal's global illumination features to say for sure whether that's a technique they use.

Answer (score 3):

Unreal does actually include a path tracing renderer, but it's not a real time one.

It serves a couple of purposes:

- A "ground truth" reference to help develop real time approximations to the slow but accurate path-traced result result.
- High quality non-realtime rendering (e.g. video creation).

The path tracer is documented at https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.2/en-US/path-tracer-in-unreal-engine/